# Autocomplete styling issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, autocomplete

I have two or more than two autocomplete on my page and two of them in a same div side by side.and after result data if I resize the page my results is overlapping or something like that as you see on image

When I type a something

and after I resize

footnote: I couldn't add any snippet because snippet is not supporting json file that's why I have to add alternate link [please click here to see demo]

and I'm using [this autocomplete plugin](https://github.com/sergiodlopes/jquery-flexdatalist) my codes

```js
$.ajaxSetup({ cache:false });
$('.hotel-list').flexdatalist({
    cache:false,
    searchContain: false,
    textProperty: '{name}',
    valueProperty: 'name',
    minLength: 3,
    focusFirstResult: true,
    selectionRequired: true,
    searchDisabled: true,
    groupBy: 'category',
    visibleProperties: ["name", "category", "area","font"],
    searchIn: ["name", "category"],
    url: 'http://yurtici.anitur.com.tr/musteri/ingoing/2017/htm/flex/hotels.json',
    relatives: '#relative'
}).on("show:flexdatalist.results", function(ev, result) {
        $.each(result, function(key, value) {
            result[key]['icon_highlight'] = value.font;
        })
    });
$('.tur-list').flexdatalist({
    cache:false,
    searchContain: false,
    textProperty: '{name}',
    valueProperty: 'font',
    minLength: 3,
    focusFirstResult: true,
    selectionRequired: true,
    searchDisabled: true,
    groupBy: 'category',
    visibleProperties: ["name", "category", "area","font"],
    searchIn: ["name", "category"],
    url: 'http://yurtici.anitur.com.tr/musteri/ingoing/2017/htm/flex/turs.json',
    relatives: '#relative'
}).on("show:flexdatalist.results", function(ev, result) {
        $.each(result, function(key, value) {
            result[key]['icon_highlight'] = value.font;
        })
    });
```

```css
.wrap{
 width:1004px;
 margin:30px auto;
}
.wrap:before,.wrap:after{
 content:"";
 display:table;
 clear:both;
}
.clearfix{
 clear:both;
}
input{
 float:left;
 margin-right:1%;
 width:45%;
 padding:12px;
 border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.item-area{
 font-style: italic;
}
.hotel-list,.tur-list{
 position:relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://projects.sergiodinislopes.pt/flexdatalist/src/jquery.flexdatalist.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="wrap">
 <input type='text' class="hotel-list">
 <input type='text' class="tur-list">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://projects.sergiodinislopes.pt/flexdatalist/src/jquery.flexdatalist.js"></script>
```

Comment: i don't have the same bug than you, when i resize, the input on the right behaves quite correctly, but when i do it with the left one, the dropdown menu moves under the right input (with good dimensions) - on firefox last version (win)

Comment: so could you try with chrome ?

Comment: and but if result is not overlapping than it's floating under another input text

Comment: the bug is the same in chrome and edge than in firefox here. I would say this comes from a javascript `resize` event, there seem to be no link with a css break point. I could have a closer look in some hours if not found.

Comment: I'll be waiting for thanks @Kaddath

Comment: from a closer look, this is the plugin that is guilty, it confuses from its various `this` variables in the `_position` function. Have no time to correct it, sorry :/

Comment: thank you so much I'll try to find a way to fix it thanks again ://